# Native C++ webrtc client on WiFi reduces video quality, but fine on calls from chrome

Tags: c++, webrtc

I have a pet project with webrtc audio-video calls. Currently calls from browser are working exactly as expected.
And I'm trying C++/Qt client based on Native C++ WebRTC (it is just a modified peer_connection_client example with modified signalling).

It works, but I've found an issue: when I make a call from one PC to another, the quality of the video is extremely reducing until bandwidth became around 250-300kbps (or 500kbps total, not sure).

As I told, there is a web version working on same signalling and I tested it out on the same PCs. The result was really surprised for me: no quality reducing and around 2000kbps network load.

Moreover, if I connect PC with cable to my router, the quality is fine and 2000kbps load, as expected.

I suppose that the problem is somewhere around wifi bandwidth estimator or so, but can't realize how can I control it's behavior.

Have someone any ideas how can I improve the quality and make webrtc use 2000kbps not 500kbps?

Thanks in advance,
Br,
Sergey

Answer (score 0):

While going forward, I've found out that I have to call `rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages()` eventually to prevent being stuck on `signalling_threads` events.

But after that a new problem occured. It is "UDP send of XXX bytes failed with error 10035" this is described at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/wmYo7AU3evI.